# How to build static executable that depends on libcurl?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, static-libraries, libcurl

I have an application in C++ under Linux (kdevelop). I want to build it statically, and I am using CMake. The application is using the curl library and I am getting lots of errors and warnings. I think that is because of the dependencies of curl.

**Is it true that curl has a lot of dependencies?** Which are they? Do you know a way to find them all fast?

Comment: You can do 'ldd ``which curl``' to find the libraries

Comment: On my box `curl` links against 38 libraries...

Comment: @P.An or for increased readability in the SO syntax `ldd $(which curl)`

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time since this question was asked, but I am having the same problem and I am stuck on it too.
First, regarding libcurl, if you download the source, it is possible to configure it such that it only contains the features you want, reducing the number of libraries it depends on.
This is done passing options to the configure script. For example,

`./configure --disable-ldap`

would remove ldap features and thus remove its dependency.

I created [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404803/create-a-fully-static-libcurl-library) explaining my whole problem, maybe some of the work I did can help you!